# During the soving the Recommendation system problem I have received the ValueError: Incompatible dimension

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

```
pivot_matrix=data.pivot_table(values='rating',columns='userId',index='title').fillna(0)[enter image description here][1]
distances, indices=model_knn.kneighbors(pivot_matrix.iloc[index:,:].values.reshape(1,-1), n_neighbors = 6)
```

During the solving above code I have got such kind of error:-

```
ValueError: Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: X.shape[1] == 21042 while Y.shape[1] == 334
```

Comment: The error says it all. The number of columns in X and Y are different and not compatible. Your input data is incorrect.

Comment: Can you please add pivot_matrix.head() data to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved:

```
distances, indices = model_knn.kneighbors(pivot_matrix.iloc[index,:].values.reshape(1,-1), n_neighbors = 5)
```